# Find cells with formula returning #ERROR

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is following - I have a macro that is filling the page with mathematical formulas. For some of the cells, the formulas are giving error values. I would like to check the whole page and whenever the error occurs, I would like to exchange the error value by 0.

My macro is following and I don´t know what I am missing to make it work:

```
sub check() 

For q = 2 To 321
    For j = 24 To 81
        A = WorksheetFunction.Type(Cells(q, j))
    If A = 16 Then Cells(q, j) = 0
    Next j
Next q 

End sub
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: no need for looping, just use one of the _flavours_ of `Specialcells()` method of `Range` object (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type` is not a member of the `WorksheetFunction` object.  I am surprised you did not report an error message.

If you want to use the `Type` function, you will need to embed it in an `Evaluate` statement.

Or you could just use the VBA `IsError` function.

The code line below checks if current cell has an error:

```
If IsError(Cells(q, j)) Then Cells(q, j) = 0
```

Comment: a little "tired" this morning ? hope you don't mind if I add something

Comment: @ShaiRado More of an issue of a kitten hanging out on my keyboard and chasing the cursor around the monitor. :-)  Thanks

Comment: @CMArg This is VBA, not Excel.  The syntax is **NOT** the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) is very handy right here

```
Range("X2:CC321").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Value = 0
```

Comment: @jirijansa, did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a alternative in the `IFERROR()` function.

Supose your mathematical formula is `A2 = 5/A1`. If `A1` is 0, that formula will return an error, but if you change it to `A2 = IFERROR(5/A1, 0)`, `A2` will be 0 if the result of `5/A1` is an error.

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee634765(v=sql.120).aspx to see the documentation for the IFERROR function.

The way I see it, it would be easier to change the macro that populates the formulas than to create a macro to do something excel has a built-in function for.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had the "anti-error" condition in the formulas, but the formulas than were too complicated to be sucessfully converted to the macro language.